# Installing MQTT client for windows 8.1

Tags: c++, mqtt, mosquitto

I've been using MQTT server/client on Ubuntu for some time without any problems.
However I tried to install a client / server on Windows 8.1 platform.
I downloaded the broker and it installed without any errors.
However I can't find the client for use as standalone, to enable me to use mosquitto_sub / mosquitto_pub.
I also need to use the client libraries in my C++ project.
Do I need eclipse-paho-mqtt-c-windows-1.0.2 to use the client libraries?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub should have been installed in

```
C:\Program Files\mosquitto
```

For devlopment the headers and .lib files should be in the devel directory at the same location to link against the libmosquitto/libmoquittopp (mosquitto.dll/mosquittopp.dll). Or as you have said you could use the paho libraries.